# Exploring threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I am looking forward to develop something to analyze the JVM threads of an application running on a server, the requirement is as below:

1. to access all the threads running in separate application
2. Print the stack of threads
3. Get to know the details of the events- logging the execution time alongside method details(executed in a particular thread)

I have worked out on 1 and 2 but unsure how to proceed with point 3 without actually updating the existing application (adding aop).

Is there any feature been provided by JVM to do so?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at what other profilers which do this are doing.  You can get the source for VisualVM for example.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into [JPDA](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/) (Java Platform Debugger Architecture).

Answer (score 1):

You can go thorugh the eclipse plugin provided for JVM monitoring..

http://jvmmonitor.org/doc/index.html